# Laravel Many-to-Many relationship with UUID as primary

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Hi I have 2 models with relationship - **Users** and **Chats**.
Model **Chats** has an **id(uuid)** field as a primary key:

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';

public $keyType = 'string';

public $incrementing = false;

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'chat_user', 'chat_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Users:

```
public function chats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Chats::class, 'chat_user', 'user_id', 'chat_id');
}
```

pivot table:

> id | chat_id(uuid) | user_id (int)

When I trying to sync user with chat I getting not null violation, because my chat_id is empty:

> Failing row contains (1, null, 1)
>   ---------------------------------^

Adding `protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];` to Chats model did not resolve the problem. What i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

My store method:

```
$chat = $this->chatRepository->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'creator_id' => Auth::id(),
    ]); // also, chat succesfully created at this step but if I'm checking dd($chat) - it doesnt contain 'id' in attributes array...

    $memberIds = $this->userRepository
        ->findWhereIn('email', collect($request->members)->pluck('email')->toArray(), ['id']);

    $chat->users()->sync($memberIds); < error at this step
```

Comment: Please show your `store` method.

Comment: Hi, look at post update please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since, $chat doesn't have `id` attribute (here is the problem) and you have already modify cast system, try save with ->save() method

```
$this->chatRepository = new ChatRepository();
$this->chatRepository->name = $request->name;
$this->creator_id = Auth::id();
$this->save();
```

Or, call again chat.

```
$chat_id = $this->chatRepository->create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'creator_id' => Auth::id(),
])->id;    
$chat = $this->chatRepository::find($chat_id);
```